# apache flink kafka streaming exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Trying to run Apache Flink kafka streaming example and getting exception-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/javaapi/consumer/SimpleConsumer
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.getPartitionsForTopic(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:607)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:280)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer082.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer082.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.kafka.ReadStreamingFromKafka.main(ReadStreamingFromKafka.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runBlocking(Client.java:252)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgramBlocking(CliFrontend.java:670)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:325)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:971)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1021)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

I have written a very basic example -

```
            StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
            properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");

            DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(),properties));
            messageStream.print();
```

Comment: Is `SimpleConsumer` contained in your jar?

Comment: i used flink-connector-kafka dependency and expected it must be shipped with it

Comment: do I need to add SimpleConsumer jar separately ?

Comment: I do not have the dependency hierarchy in mind. Just check your jar, for example via `unzip -l youJar.jar | grep SimpleConsumer`. If it is not contained, you need to add it by adapting your jar assembly configuration.

Comment: @ABC, how did you build your program jar? I tried reproducing your problem by using Flink's quickstart archetypes. I just added the `flink-connector-kafka` dependency and everything worked. Judging from your package name, can it be that you've created you example within the flink-examples module? How did you modify the flink-examples pom.xml to build your program jar then? Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: I needed to copy few  Zookeper and kafka jars like zclient etc. then it started working , this is how my pom looks like https://github.com/abhishek-ch/evolveML/blob/master/flink/kafka-flink-example/pom.xml